# Struts - actions mapping - while choosing options

Tags: java, struts2

I am currently working on a struts2 project. In my project the user is given 2 options randomly of the many stored in the database out of which he selects any 1. the option that is selected is considered the winner and the one that is not is considered loser. The number of wins and losses for each entry is noted. That means i need to send both the winner and loser to the action and which 1 is sent will depend on what the user clicks. Also i have 2 work with objects simple strings is not enough.

I don't know how to go about this because whatever i name my options will be the name i have to give in the action. can someone tell me how to get the name of the option clicked. what should i do in my actions.

also if want that the user need not click the submit button after clicking the option what modifications should i do?

For both the above questions it would be best if the solution conforms to the OO Principles

Comment: why your input parameters and actions have to be matching, create two hidden varibales actually 3 (one to told which is winner) and set them using javascript depending upon what user selects and send them to back end.. That's it..

Comment: even i was thinking about that. but is that clean and the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make an action that handles both options at the same time (So both winner or Loser). Or you need to sent multiple requests (for example with ajax) for each of them.

Comment: so do you say i have actions wit properties winner and loser. also how do is set them with the jsps. do you ask me to something as what is said in the comment to my question by vishwanath.

Comment: Well the architecture of your design is not very clear to me. Assuming you have a website where people can choose between 2 items. For example 2 random pictures and the user chooses the most beautiful. When the user clicks on one of the images a request is done to an action with the following data: idImage1, idImage2, idWinner. Now you can add all the data on server side with just one request. Optionally you can sent 2 new images back for the next decision.

Comment: option 2 is that you sent 2 request onclick. One to set winner, One to set loser. Data would me like, IdImage, booleanIsWinner. I think this option is harder because you have to make 2 different actions. If something goes wrong on one of the actions you would need something to cancel the transactions of both. Validation is harder aswell and you have to maintain more code.